# Change row value's of the Gtk.ListStore

Tags: c#, gtk#

I fill treeview in my project by next method:

```
            Gtk.ListStore treeview1ListStore = new Gtk.ListStore (typeof (String), typeof (String));
protected void FillTreeView(TreeView MyTreeView, Gtk.ListStore TreeViewListStore, String[] Column1, String[] Column2)
{
    for(Int32 i=0;i!=Column1.Length;i++)
    {
       TreeViewListStore.AppendValues(Column1[i],Column2[i]);
    }
    MyTreeView.Model=TreeViewListStore
}
```

I call this method by the next way:

```
String[] column1 = new String[]{"column1_1","column1_2","column1_3"};
String[] column2 = new String[]{"column2_1","column2_2","column2_3"};
this.FillTreeView(this.treeview1, treeview1ListStore, column1,column2);
```

Now I want to change some of treeview values, but when I use:

```
    foreach(Gtk.Object currentNode in treeviewListStore)
    {

    }
```

my program crashes.
How can I change value of the ListStore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you thought of using the SetValues() function?
Here is an example that will fill only the selected raw with the values you want.
You can easily modify this code so you can change values to any specific rows using TreePath:

```
TreeIter iter; TreeModel model;

if( MyTreeView.Selection.GetSelected(out model, out iter))
    TreeViewListStore.SetValues(iter,"column1_1","column1_2","column1_3");
```

Comment: I solve my problem by next code: protected void UpdateDataOfListStore(String InsertingData, ref ListStore MyListStore)
 {
  TreeIter tmpTreeIter;

  for(System.Numerics.BigInteger i=0; MyListStore.GetIterFromString(out tmpTreeIter, i.ToString())==true;i++)
  {
   MyListStore.SetValue(tmpTreeIter, 0, 
                        MyListStore.GetValue(tmpTreeIter,0)+InsertingData);
  }
 }

Comment: Perhaps you could add your comment as a solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where an update is made on a specific 'row' - the columnNumber is used as index in model :

```
    public void updateDataOfListStoreInTreeView(ListStore mListstore, int ColumnNumber, params string[] str)
    {
        try {
            bool bUpdated = false;
            TreeIter tmpTreeIter; 

            mListStore.GetIterFirst(out tmpTreeIter);
            object o = mListStore.GetValue(tmpTreeIter, ColumnNumber);
            while(o!=null)
            {
                if(o.ToString()==str[ColumnNumber].ToString()) {
                    mListStore.SetValues(tmpTreeIter,str); // update row
                    bUpdated=true;
                    break;
                }
                if(mListStore.IterNext(ref tmpTreeIter)) {
                    o = mListStore.GetValue(tmpTreeIter, ColumnNumber);
                }
                else 
                    o = null;
            }

            if(!bUpdated)  
                mListStore.AppendValues (str); // Add some data to the store
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("WARNING: adding to treeview caused exception");
        }
    }
```